# dbus_connection_send failed duo to Disconnection

Tags: dbus

Recently I use dbus as IPC, but I encounter some problems:

- how to process send message failed: The `dbus_connection_send` can send a dbus message, But the document say:

  > Because this only queues the message, the only reason it can fail is
  >   lack of memory. Even if the connection is disconnected, no error will
  >   be returned. If the function fails due to lack of memory, it returns
  >   FALSE. The function will never fail for other reasons; even if the
  >   connection is disconnected, you can queue an outgoing message, though
  >   obviously it won't be sent.

  so how to process this case when connection disconnect to ensure all the message in outgoing queue be sent successfully
- how to process connection disconnected when receive message by `dbus_connection_dispatch`, my code like this, But I think it will lose some message when reconnect to dbus

void DbusMessageWrapper::messageDispatchThreadFunction()
{
start:
    struct pollfd *pollFd = &m_pollFd;
    if (!dbus_connection_set_watch_functions(m_dbusConnection, addWatch, removeWatch, NULL, this, NULL))
    {
        TONLY_ERROR("dbus_connection_set_watch_functions failed");
        return;
    }

`if (!dbus_connection_add_filter(m_dbusConnection, messageProcessFunction, this, NULL))
{
    TONLY_INFO("dbus_connection_add_filter failed");
    return;
}

int iret = 0;
for (; !m_isShuttingDown;)
{
    iret = poll(pollFd, 1, -1);
    if (iret < 0)
    {
        ///If poll return -1, we think that poll does not work on current plateform, so emit a ALERT log and exit application 
        TONLY_ALERT("poll for dbus fd failed, the application will exit.");
        exit(1);
    }

    /**
     * If poll return POLLHUP/POLLRDHUP/POLLERR event, we think the dbus connection have disconnected from dbus deamon
     * we should release the request name and close current dbus connection, then reconnect to the dbus deamon,
     * aslo add the message observer watch to dbus connection again
     */
    if ((pollFd->revents & POLLHUP) || (pollFd->revents & POLLRDHUP) || (pollFd->revents & POLLERR))
    {
        TONLY_ERROR("poll error event occured, will reconnect to dbus deamon.");
        dbusDisConnect();
        dbusConnect();

        ///reinstall the message observer
        auto observers = m_observers;
        m_observers.clear();
        for (auto it = observers.begin(); it != observers.end(); it++)
        {
            addMessageObserver({it->second});
        }

        goto start;
    }

    unsigned int flags = 0;
    if (pollFd->revents & POLLIN)
    {
        flags |= DBUS_WATCH_READABLE;
    }

    ///wait for there are enougth memory
    while (!dbus_watch_handle(m_watch, flags))
    {
        TONLY_ERROR("Dbus need more memory");
        sleep(1);
    }

    while (dbus_connection_get_dispatch_status(m_dbusConnection) == DBUS_DISPATCH_DATA_REMAINS)
    {
        dbus_connection_dispatch(m_dbusConnection);
    }
}`

}

Answer (score 0):

It is **highly** recommended that you use a D-Bus library *other* than libdbus, as libdbus is fiddly to use correctly, as you are finding. If possible, use [GDBus](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-convenience.html) or [QtDBus](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdbus-index.html) instead, as they are much higher-level bindings which are easier to use. If you need a lower-level binding, [sd-bus](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd-bus.html) is more modern than libdbus.

Both higher-level D-Bus libraries handle message transmission failure and disconnection differently from libdbus. Since it’s not entirely clear exactly what problems you’re having, I suggest you read their documentation and see if they meet your use case.

Comment: sd-bus is in libsystemd, can I use sd-bus api without install libsystemd

Comment: No, you cannot. If your license is compatible, you could potentially copy the sd-bus implementation into your source code.